# HTA Archive Bundles

Tags: bundle, hta

I am writing a small HTA file to do a simple report for myself. I would like to bundle multiple resources into a single file for distribution (images, javascript, etc.)

As I was perusing the MS documentation I came across a reference to HTA Archives: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332530.aspx. Unfortunately, the documentation has been removed (even before the WayBack Machine got a look at it).

What is the best way to distribute related items? Is there an HTA Archive format?

Comment: Just use a `ZIP` file and reference all your resources relative to the extraction path.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the URL is how it is meant to be it is an archive of the `The ABCs of HTAs` - From the page *"Previous articles posted as part of the series The ABCs of HTAs"*. So it's an archive of previous articles, if even list the previous articles in the table underneath the heading, it hasn't been removed it's as it was suppose to be.

Comment: Unfortunate... I was hoping there was a hidden gem.

Comment: What would that give you that a `ZIP` doesn't? The only thing close to that I've heard of before the [`MHTML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) *(MIME HTML)* format Microsoft brought out a while ago as a Archive HTML format *(See [RFC2557](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2557))*.

Comment: I'm looking for it to be executable, I was expecting something like HTZ (just a zip of files with HTAs inside, executable on click). MHTML may work, but the compilation sounds harder than I'm looking for

Comment: Sorry Archive HTML format is the wrong word it's more an Embedded HTML format because all the resources are embedded in the file as multiparts.

Comment: I saved a page as MHT, renamed to HTA, and ran it. It did *not* like the embedded content, some more experimentation may prove otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure `MSHTA.exe` will know how to handle MHTML to honest but worthy effort!

Comment: I use PrimalScript package option as an executable.

Comment: @JeffereyCave have you looked into base64 image URIs? Although that will not work on WinXP.

Comment: @AaronGillion More effort than I was really interested in, but a reasonable work around. Write it up as an answer (I'll probably end up adding to it)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put your HTA in the root of a zip file. All your resources could be in an `assets` folder, and any libraries could be in a `lib` folder. This is pretty much industry standard. Or you could host all your files on a web server and have the user download a batch script that uses `BITSADMIN.exe` to copy the files to the local machine and build the filetree. I could help with this as I have used this method to distribute small projects before.